# Woocommerce New Order Confirmation Multiple Email Provider

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a issue with new order confirmation in woocommerce, 
I have a notification@domain.com as my new order confirmation email, and added the smtp setup, everything is working fine, but when I try to added a different email provider like notification@gmail.com, notification@hotmail.com as the recipients, only the notification@domain.com able to receive the email but not gmail and hotmail account.

The site is hosting in aws, and email provider is intermedia, is anyone facing a similar issue like me?

Comment: Is it possible you're not authenticating with [Intermedia's mail server](https://kb.intermedia.net/Article/598)? Sometimes that will prevent outside email delivery.

Comment: @DanWich The email will through intermedia's mail server. In general, create a email in the mail server and send to gmail/hotmail is working fine, but the new order confirmation email is not, cause I added few different email provider email in the list.